# Regarding the (integral-domain) tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I read through the [tag-merging and synonyms](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms?cb=1) thread today, and was reminded that we have three different, closely-related tags, namely: [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration), [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral), and [definite-integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-integral). I was confused by this, but am willing to stand by the reasoning given for the distinction there and in other threads.

Later, though, I discovered that the tag [integral-domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-domain) lists [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) as a "related tag", which is ridiculous! How is it that this happened, and can anything be done to remove this spurious link?

Comment: In fact ([tag:integration]) and ([tag:integral]) are now [synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/integration/synonyms).

Comment: I'm sure someone was just confused about the domain over which their integral was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the "Related Tags" are those that are tagged along with the first tag in some question.  When you were writing the question above there was [one question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529936/8348) which was tagged both [integral-domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-domain) and [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration).  (This has since been changed.)

Once the system recovers, the "Related Tags" for [integral-domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-domain) should no longer show [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration).  (It appears it already has.)

Comment: Excellent! Good to know it's that simple a fix. I'll be able to take care of it on my own if I encounter such a thing in the future.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Good catch! The "related tag" list is indeed a great way to discover questions that are either (i) hopeless mistagged or (ii) extremely interesting!

Comment: @WillieWong It would certainly be an interesting question if someone could make sense of something like "integrating along curves in integrable modules for quantum groups over integral domains".